# How to remove objects from object array based on another Int array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I am trying to remove objects from an object array based on another int array using java script.

Int array contains ids from object array. I want to removes objects from object array which doesn't have id from Integer array.

Example:

```
var x =[{name : 'mark' , Id : '10' , color:'green'},
  {name : 'hen' , Id : '15' , color:'blue'} ,
  {name : 'joy' , Id : '30' , color:'yellow'},
  {name : 'mick' , Id : '15' , color:'red'},
  {name : 'nick' , Id : '40' , color:'black'}] ; 

var y =['40','15'];
```

From the above 2 arrays, I want to remove objects from x array whose id is not present in y array;

Result Should be :

```
x =[{name : 'hen' , Id : '15' , color:'blue'},
  {name : 'mick' , Id : '15' , color:'red'},
  {name : 'nick' , Id : '40' , color:'black'}];
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and check if `Id` is in `y` array using [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
var x = [{name : 'mark' , Id : '10' , color:'green'}, {name : 'hen' , Id : '15' , color:'blue'} , {name : 'joy' , Id : '30' , color:'yellow'}, {name : 'mick' , Id : '15' , color:'red'}, {name : 'nick' , Id : '40' , color:'black'}] ;
var y = ['40','15'];

const res = x.filter(a => y.includes(a.Id));
console.log(res)
```